# How to overwrite JS variable with wp_localize _script?

Tags: javascript, theme-customizer, wp-localize-script

The function `wp_localize_script( $handle, $name, $data );` does not work when trying to overwrite the same variable, that is when calling the function second time with the same $handle and $name but with other $data value.

How can this problem be solved?

Comment: Can you provide some context? Why do you need to overwrite the data?

Comment: For example in **customizer**. When theme settings are changed, it refreshes the preview. Theme settings are re-retrieved and their output in front-end  needs to be overwriten.
The order of actions without customizer.
1. on `after_setup_theme` action theme settings are retrieved using `get_option()`
2. on 'wp_head', scripts are enqueued using `wp_enqueue_script` and JS vars are initialized using `wp_localize_script`.
On Customizer preview again `wp_head` filter is used.
`get_option()` is again called and frontend is reinitialized. Now `wp_localize_script` have to be called again.

Comment: This answer my help http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/108364/74733

Comment: Wow, thanks! I have to test this. Don't know if it works also with the new theme switcher in customizer.