# What about Deferring a localized script?

Tags: wp-localize-script, l10n

I would love to defer the loading of the script for a plugin, Simple Locator, which uses Google.maps API.

However it uses `wp_localize_script`, which prints a `wpsl_locator` javascript object in the HTML page (to include options), which calls on `google-maps` API's `google` object, which isn't loaded yet.

I thought that possibly I could fake it out by hacking the plugin and adding `wpsl_locator = new Object()` via another (deferred) script, which would include hard-coded options:

`wpsl_locator.map_options={[truncated]{style:google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL,}};`

But one problem is that it would break on plugin updating.

It doesn't look like `wp_deregister_script( 'simple-locator' );` is removing the i10n output that `wp_localize_script` is generating.

Is there a recommended way of handling this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is basically from [this SO post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/236724/48604):

When wordpress "localizes" a script, what it does is has php print out `<script></script>` tags with javascript objects in them that are then accessible within the DOM to the scripts you are "sending" the parameters to.

If I understand correctly, the extension of `WP_Scripts` simple adds a filter, referenced by the (arbitrary) handle, `script_l10n`, then sends that filtered variable, `$110n` through to the parent method, `localize`, which is where WPs array of arrays to "localize" gets sent.

```
class Filterable_Scripts extends WP_Scripts
{
    function localize( $handle, $object_name, $l10n )
    {
        $l10n = apply_filters( 'script_l10n', $l10n, $handle, $object_name );
        return parent::localize($handle, $object_name, $l10n);
    }
}
```

Then we replace `$GLOBALS['wp_scripts']` with our new filterable one.

```
function my_filter_script_intlization() {
    $GLOBALS['wp_scripts'] = new Filterable_Scripts;
}
add_action( 'init', 'my_filter_script_intlization');
```

And now we can hook into the filter to modify the `l10n` string from the plugin (once we've used `print_r()` or something to figure out what it is).

```
function se108362_example_filter($l10n, $handle, $object_name ) {
    if('simple-locator' == $handle && 'wpsl_locator' == $object_name) {

        $phyt_i10n_settings = array(
            'mapTypeId' => 'roadmap',
            'mapTypeControl' => false,
            'zoom' => 8,
            'panControl' => false,
            'zoomControlOptions' => array('style' => '') // was google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL
            );


        $l10n['l10n_print_after'] = 'wpsl_locator.map_options = ' . json_encode($phyt_i10n_settings);

        return $l10n;
    }
    return $l10n;
}

add_filter('script_l10n', 'se108362_example_filter', 10 , 3);
```

Then in the js I replace the `l10n` variables with my hard-coded ones:

```
wpsl_locator.map_options.zoomControlOptions.style = google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL;
wpsl_locator.map_options.styles = wpsl_locator.mapstyles;
```

For some reason the `Filterable_Scripts` sub-class seems to break the Advanced Custom Fields script loading:

```
public function my_filter_script_intlization() {
    //These exist here:
    var_dump($GLOBALS['wp_scripts']->registered['acf-field-group']);
    var_dump($GLOBALS['wp_scripts']->registered['acf-input']);
    $GLOBALS['wp_scripts'] = new \PhytJobs\FilterableScripts;
    // But now they are gone
    print_r(isset($GLOBALS['wp_scripts']->registered['acf-field-group']));
}
```

My workaround is to do this:

```
public function my_filter_script_intlization() {
    $acf_field_group = $GLOBALS['wp_scripts']->registered['acf-field-group'];
    $acf_input = $GLOBALS['wp_scripts']->registered['acf-input'];
    $GLOBALS['wp_scripts'] = new \PhytJobs\FilterableScripts;
    $GLOBALS['wp_scripts']->registered['acf-field-group'] = $acf_field_group;
    $GLOBALS['wp_scripts']->registered['acf-input'] = $acf_input;
}
```

But I'm wondering why the sub-classing is breaking it in the first place.

Someone suggested that the issue is caused by hooking the `my_filter_script_intlization` action too late, after `$WP_Scripts` has already been partly populated. I'm still a little unclear on how that works or why ACF would be the problem.

UPDATE, ACF only loads its scripts in Admin and the other plugin only `l10n` in the front end so I just wrapped the `action` and `filter` hook in a `!is_admin` test and ACF has nothing to complain about.